# Issue in connecting AzureDevOps Git repo using Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I have a Git repo in AzureDevOPS and I am using Visual Studio code to work on angularjs based application. The repo is already setup in VSTS. I was able to connect to the repo without any issues but suddenly today while reconnecting to it I saw the below error at the right hand bottom bar of Visual Studio Code

[image]

Here goes my git version available in my system:
git version 2.9.2.windows.1

VSCode Version Details:

```
Version: 1.47.2 (user setup)
Commit: 17299e413d5590b14ab0340ea477cdd86ff13daf
Date: 2020-07-15T18:22:06.216Z
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue

Comment: Is the VSCode upgraded recently? Have you tried re-installing the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following items:

1. Check logs in `%AppData%\Code\logs` and `Ctrl-shift-p => Show Logs => Extension Host` to see if there is useful information.
2. Disable the `Azure Repos` extension, close VSCode.
3. Clean caches in `%AppData%\Code\Cache` and `%AppData%\Code\CachedData`, open VSCode and enable the extension.
4. If the issue persists, try to uninstall the extension and re-install it.
5. Instead of using `https://xxx.visualstudio.com`, try
   using the new URL: `https://dev.azure.com/xxx`.